# Difference between button and which in mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between `event.button` and `event.which` in Javascript mouse events?

Comment: `button` for `mouseDown` and `mouseUp`, `buttons` for `mouseMove`, and don't use [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### event.button

Indicates which mouse button caused the event.

### event.which

According to jQuery's documentation:

> > ...event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for right. Use event.which instead of event.button.

### Difference

In all modern browsers (IE8+) `event.button` will give you the following values:

```
0   Specifies the left mouse-button
1   Specifies the middle mouse-button
2   Specifies the right mouse-button
```

While in IE8 and earlier:

```
1   Specifies the left mouse-button
4   Specifies the middle mouse-button
2   Specifies the right mouse-button
```

`event.which` standardize these results by providing you the following values:

```
1   Specifies the left mouse-button
2   Specifies the middle mouse-button
3   Specifies the right mouse-button
```

Comment: Hm yes, but both seem to indicate the mouse button - what exactly is the difference?

Comment: Let me give you a further example.

Comment: @chopper, I believe my last edit answers your question.

Comment: Yes, specifically for the mouse events. For the keyboard events it normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm relatively shy to the last solution despite my upvote. According to the MDN documentation :

[`This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which)

So, [MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button) is still prefered.
An interesting (case) alternative could be [MouseEvent.buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/buttons) which permits you to determine all buttons pressed when the event is triggered.